# Passing a list of lists by value is not updating in Scheme language

Tags: matrix, scheme, lisp, racket, linear-algebra

I am trying to write a function in Scheme which will calculate the rank of a given matrix (in the form of a list of lists) using Gaussian Elimination method.

I'll explain what I am trying to do in the code and would appreciate if anyone could tell me what I did wrong \ how to correct it.

In `iter-rows` function, I iterate over the rows and perform Gaussian Elimination on each row to make the matrix into row echelon form:

- `below-pivot` will basically perform the elimination step below the pivot in the given row.
- `factor-rec` here I calculate the factor needed to multiply a row during the elimination process.
- `elimination` function performs the elimination itself over the rest of the rows below the pivot.
- As for the `update-matrix` function, it will subtract a multiple of one row from another.
- Finally, count all non-zero rows to find the rank.

Since lists are immutable I am passing their value with every call.

Here's the code for reference:

```
#lang racket

(define (rank matrix)
  (define (iter-rows index rows-len matrix)
    (if (= index rows-len)
        matrix
          (let ((pivot (list-ref (list-ref matrix index) index)))
            (if (= pivot 0)
                (iter-rows (+ index 1) rows-len matrix)
                (begin
                  (below-pivot (+ index 1) rows-len matrix pivot index)
                  (iter-rows (+ index 1) rows-len matrix))))))

  (define (below-pivot from-index rows-len matrix pivot i)
    (if (= from-index rows-len)
        matrix
        (begin
          (factor-rec (+ from-index 1) rows-len matrix i pivot)
          (below-pivot (+ from-index 1) rows-len matrix pivot i))))

  (define (factor-rec j rows-len matrix i pivot)
    (if (= j rows-len)
        matrix
        (begin
          (let ([factor (/ (list-ref (list-ref matrix j) i) pivot)])
            (elimination i i rows-len matrix j factor)))))

  (define (elimination k i rows-len matrix j factor)
    (if (= k rows-len)
        matrix
        (begin
          (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)
          (elimination (+ k 1) i rows-len matrix j factor))))

  (define (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)
    (let ((new-cdr (- (list-ref (list-ref matrix j) k)
                      (* factor (list-ref (list-ref matrix i) k)))))
      (list (list-ref matrix i)
            (cons new-cdr (list-tail (list-ref matrix j) k)))))

  (let ((rows-len (length matrix)))
    (iter-rows 0 rows-len matrix))

  (define (count-nonzero-rows matrix)
    (let loop ((matrix matrix) (rank- 0))
      (cond 
          ((null? matrix) rank-)
          ((not (all-zeroes? (car matrix))) 
           (loop (cdr matrix) (+ rank- 1)))
          (else (loop (cdr matrix) rank-)))))

  (let* ((rank (count-nonzero-rows matrix)))
    rank))

(define (all-zeroes? row)
  (for/and ([x row]) (= x 0)))
```

I'm new to Scheme so would appreciate any other tips as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to use the return values of a bunch of those function calls that you're currently ignoring...

Comment: Might also want to read https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html#%28part._.Where_to_.Put_.Parentheses%29

Comment: @Shawn "Racket isn’t C" haha thanks I'll fix my code's template tomorrow. As for the `use the return values`, do you mean by using `set!`? As seen here https://docs.racket-lang.org/control-manual/index.html#%28idx._%28gentag._5._%28lib._control%2Fscribblings%2Fcontrol-manual..scrbl%29%29%29 ?

Comment: If you call a function that returns a modified list and don't capture that value to use later, what's the point? Like in `(begin (update-matrix ...) (elimination...))` and a few other spots. The first function's result is just getting ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
#lang racket

(define (extract matrix i j)
  (vector-ref (vector-ref matrix i) j))
  
(define (swap-rows! matrix i j)
  (let ((tmp (vector-ref matrix i)))
    (vector-set! matrix i (vector-ref matrix j))
    (vector-set! matrix j tmp)))

(define (scale-row! matrix i factor)
  (define (vector-scale vec factor)
    (vector-map (curry * factor) vec))
  (let* ((row (vector-ref matrix i))
         (scaled-row (vector-scale row factor)))
    (vector-set! matrix i scaled-row)))

(define (eliminate-rows! matrix i j pivot)
  (define (eliminate-row! matrix i j pivot)
    (when (< i (vector-length matrix))
      (let* ((element-i-j (extract matrix i j))
             (factor (/ element-i-j pivot)))
        (scale-row! matrix i factor)
        (eliminate-row! matrix (add1 i) j pivot))))
  (eliminate-row! matrix (add1 i) j pivot))

(define (gaussian-rank matrix (i 0) (j 0) (rank 0))
  (cond ((>= i (vector-length matrix)) rank)
        ((zero? (extract matrix i j)) (gaussian-rank matrix (add1 i) j rank))
        (else
          (swap-rows! matrix i rank)
          (let ((pivot (extract matrix rank j)))
            (when (not (zero? pivot))
              (scale-row! matrix rank (/ 1 pivot))
              (eliminate-rows! matrix rank j pivot))
            (gaussian-rank matrix (add1 i) (add1 j) (add1 rank))))))

(define mat (vector #(1 2 3) #(0 1 2) #(0 0 1)))
(gaussian-rank mat) ;;=> 1
```

The "matrix" should be a vector. (Probably one should introduce a struct).
`extract` returns the element in a matrix in the i-th row and j-th column.
`swap-rows!` takes a matrix and rows the i-th and j-th row.
`scale-row!` scales a row multiplying each of the i-th row element by a factor.
`eliminate-rows!` uses  these two functions to eliminat-through a matrix.
And these operations are used to calculat the gaussian rank.

## More efficient solution

Perhaps more efficient is this version:

```
(define (get-row matrix i)
  (vector-ref matrix i))

(define (get-element matrix i j)
  (vector-ref (vector-ref matrix i) j))

(define (swap-rows! matrix i j)
  (let ((tmp (vector-ref matrix i)))
    (vector-set! matrix i (vector-ref matrix j))
    (vector-set! matrix j tmp)))

(define-syntax while
  (syntax-rules () ((_ pred b1 ...) (let loop () (when pred b1 ... (loop))))))

(define (gaussian-rank matrix)
  (let* ((nrows (vector-length matrix))
         (ncols (if (zero? nrows) 0 (vector-length (vector-ref matrix 0))))
         (rank 0))
    (for ([ncol (in-range ncols)])
      (let ([pivot-row rank])
        (while (and (< pivot-row nrows)
                     (zero? (get-element matrix pivot-row ncol)))
            (set! pivot-row (add1 pivot-row)))
        (unless (= pivot-row nrows)
          (swap-rows! matrix pivot-row rank)
          (let ([pivot-value (get-element matrix rank ncol)])
            (for ([nrow (in-range (add1 rank) nrows)])
              (let* ([factor (/ (get-element matrix nrow ncol) pivot-value)]
                     [scaled-diffed-row (vector-map (lambda (x y) (- x (* factor y)))
                                      (get-row matrix nrow)
                                      (get-row matrix rank))])
                (vector-set! matrix nrow scaled-diffed-row))))
          (set! rank (add1 rank)))))
     rank))
```

Here, the same processing is done but working preferably with loops and thus perhaps faster.

Call it by:

```
> (define mat (vector #(1 2 3) #(4 5 6) #(7 8 9)))
> (gaussian-rank mat)
2
> mat
'#(#(1 2 3) #(0 -3 -6) #(0 0 0))
```

the `syntax-rule` takes:

```
        (while (and (< pivot-row nrows)
                     (zero? (get-element matrix pivot-row ncol)))
            (set! pivot-row (add1 pivot-row)))
```

and matches

```
`_`:    while
`pred`: (and (< pivot-row nrows)
                     (zero? (get-element matrix pivot-row ncol)))
`b1`:   (set! pivot-row (add1 pivot-row))
`...`:  in this case nothing
```

and transforms this - while nothing is yet evaluated - to:

```
(let loop ()
  (when (and (< pivot-row nrows)
                     (zero? (get-element matrix pivot-row ncol)))
    (set! pivot-row (add1 pivot-row))
    (loop))
```

and then evalutes this generated code in-situ (in exactly the environment/place where the `while` expression was invoked).
This code transformation is done in compile time.
This is how a lisp macro works.

Comment: Thanks, this is written clearly and pretty easy to understand (did read about most procedures in the documentation as well). Just a couple of questions to make sure I understood. Since vectors are mutable, you just passed a reference of `matrix` and by using `vector-set!` you changed the values through the reference? Also, `when` and `unless` are basically `if statements` without an `else`?

Comment: And can you please provide a little bit of explanation about the way you used `syntax-rules`? I couldn't really understand how you used it in your answer (read about it here https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-rules%29%29).

Comment: Welcome! `when` and `unless` => yes, if you use just one branch of `if/else` statements either the `consequent` or the `alternative` only.
I used vector because of speed => the access to positions is faster - it is also faster because with vectors the elements must be of one type. Since the matrix is purely numerical it is good to restrict for numbers and gain in speed. And yes, `vector-set!` mutates the value in situ.

Comment: `syntax-rules` defines a macro. e.g. http://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme_syntax_e.html
it takes an expression matching a pattern and transforms it to another expression.
In this case: `(_ pred b1 ...)` if an expression starts with `_`=>`while`, then match next expression as a conditional (`pred`) and then at least one expression as a consequent `b1` plus zero or more expressions `...`.  And transform them to:
`(let loop () (when pred b1 ... (loop)))` where you replace `pred` by what was matched to `pred`, `b1` what was matched in the pattern to `b1` and `...` what was matche to it.

Comment: @SA.93 I attached at the end of my answer how the expression in the code it gets evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a recurrent problem with your functions. For instance,

```
  (define (elimination k i rows-len matrix j factor)
    (if (= k rows-len)
        matrix
        (begin
          (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)
          (elimination (+ k 1) i rows-len matrix j factor))))
```

I *assume* `update-matrix` (inside the `begin`) is supposed to return an updated matrix. Yet the returned value is ignored, and the old value of `matrix` is used again, in the call to `elimination`.

You can fix this in a purely syntactical (i.e. mechanistic) manner by changing `begin` to `let*` in the above, as

```
  (define (elimination k i rows-len matrix j factor)
    (if (= k rows-len)
        matrix
        (let* ([matrix (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)])  ; <<< here
          (elimination (+ k 1) i rows-len matrix j factor))))
```

After this is done for all functions with this problem, running e.g.

```
(rank '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
```

produces the following error,

```
. . list-ref: index too large for list
  index: 2
  in: '((1 2 3) (0 7 8 9))
```

inside `update-matrix`. You will need to debug this further.

Another thing is, all these functions actually implement the same "folding" pattern, passing along an "accumulator" value, as it is being updated, from step to step.

You've coded it in an awkward manner though, passing around many of all those parameters without change. This style is used in languages without the concept of nested scope, like Prolog. But in Scheme this is normally coded with an inner definition, or an equivalent `letrec` or named `let` construct.

And you're already using this construct in your `count-nonzero-rows`.

Following this pattern, the above function becomes

```
  (define (elimination k i rows-len matrix j factor)
    (let loop ((k k)
               (matrix matrix))
      (if (= k rows-len)
         matrix
         (loop (+ k 1)
               (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)))))

   ;;   (let* ([matrix (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)]) 
   ;;     (elimination (+ k 1) i rows-len matrix j factor))))
   ;;                  ^^^^^^             ^^^^^^
   ;;                  only these two arguments are changing
```

But actually, this folding pattern is already available in Racket as [`for/fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29), so you can just use that, similar to how you already use `for/and` in `all-zeroes?`.

Comment: Seeing this (`(let* ([matrix (update-matrix matrix j k i factor)])`) in your example made me understand what Shawn meant by "capturing the value", I was trying a totally different thing... About the manner I coded this program, my professor said that Scheme is a functional language so there's almost no imperative methods such as loops, therefore, almost always use recursions, and this is what I tried to do (the only function I found by accident was the `count-nonzero-rows` that's why I guess it's written well compared to others), guess the keyword was "almost always"... Thanks for explaining!

Comment: you're welcome. :) the "named let" construct is how the loops are usually coded, in the "naked" Scheme. Racket has all kinds of additional stuff. your way with passing all the variables along is really unusual in Scheme, as I said in the answer, because in Scheme we have the notion of scope and so an inner function has access to the variables in the containing function, and we only need to pass along the variables that are actually changing, to model the loop. and the unchanging variables are just left in the containing function's scope. the name "loop" is arbitrary and could be anything.

Comment: your way, could be used in encoding some mutual recursive functions, maybe.  re: the loops, yes, we encode them with tail-recursive functions, because they are equivalent. tail calls are like jumps, and loops too jump back to the top to re-enter the loop body, with the updated loop variables - just like the tail recursive calls do.

Comment: @SA.93 Yes, recursion is a very functional and powerful way to handle complex problems. And your teacher do the right thing to teach you that and encourage you to use that. However, luckily, lisp languages like Scheme/Racket and Common Lisp (and Clojure) are not purely functional languages. They do have possibilities of mutation.
`let` is the assignment in lisp. In contrast to other languages, you can sharply define until when the assigned variable should be valid. Using `let*` one can use defined variables in the immediately following assignment. It is like nesting `let` expressions.

Comment: if you want to learn a language, re-type any function you find, literally, with your fingers. then go over every detail new to you, reading the manual, trying it out and testing some examples at the REPL, and document it for yourself with comments etc.. you can't learn to play the piano by reading musical score. (usually at least :) ).